# database- store the string as it is

Tags: sql, jdbc

I have written an alter script to add a column to database:

```
ALTER TABLE tr_rtl
ADD (ID_STR_RT1 varchar2(178));
```

I am trying to store a digital signature into the database using jdbc. The actual digital signature is:

```
tNBc41Qlb3Zov2pPStcbj71DWB6hBxsByessFJsfvizQhIe+39TfzDOUDaCt4AmJ+uUYmQzDZAZ/=
```

but in the database it is being stored as:

```
TNBC41QLB3ZOV2PPSTCBJ71DWB6HBXSBYESSFJSFVIZQHIE+39TFZDOUDACT4AMJ+UUYMQZDZAZ/=
```

which is in uppercase.   **How can I store the digital signature as it is**?

Thanks

Comment: It seems you are using Oracle DB (based on `VARCHAR2`). Could you please post code (else sql if doing manually) that does the insert.

Comment: Sounds like a character set issue. See http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14117_01/server.101/b10749/ch2charset.htm

Comment: no matter how it is store, it remains same when u retrive that string for manipulation

Comment: Sorry, I can't reproduce this.  Can you please share the JDBC code you're using to store the data in the database?